Lubuntu 20.04 "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs"
Following guidance from the MS site, I opened a terminal window and installed multiple versions of the .NET runtime using these commands:
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:~$ DOTNET_FILE=dotnet-runtime-8.0.11-linux-x64.tar.gz
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:~$ export DOTNET_ROOT=$(pwd)/.dotnet
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:~$ mkdir -p "$DOTNET_ROOT" && tar zxf "$DOTNET_FILE" -C "$DOTNET_ROOT"
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:~$ export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools

This appeared to work well, and if I check the dotnet version it shows this:
$ dotnet --version
9.0.100

HOWEVER....if I open a new terminal window I can no longer access dotnet. For example, I get this if I try to check the version:
$ dotnet --version
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Assuming it to be a problem with the PATH, I copied the PATH from the original terminal window that I used to install dotnet, and edited ~/.bashrc to add all of the entries to the PATH.
So if I now open a new terminal window and check the PATH, it is this:
/home/myuser/bin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/myuser/bin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/.dotnet:/home/myuser/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/.dotnet:/home/myuser/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/.dotnet:/home/myuser/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/.dotnet:/home/myuser/.dotnet/tools:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet:/home/myuser/Downloads/.dotnet/tools

...but I still get the same error if I try to access dotnet ("It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs").
Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm a bit of a Linux noob.
